# Xamarin - The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context

Tags: xamarin, resources

I've googled till I'm blue in the fingers trying to find a resolution to this issue. I've tried several things but nothing helps. I've got Xamarin and Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I had everything working on a previous PC a few months back. Now I have a new one and am just now getting Xamarin set up. I have a few demo and self hacked solutions I was working with. Now all of them give me the above error message. I've made sure the namespace is correct in all modules. The solutions are really small. Nothing fancy at all. Basically Hello World stuff so I'm at a failure to figure out why it fails now. Case in Point: The Hello World that is failing is one HelloWorld.cs file and a few PNGs in the Resources tree along with a main.xml.
If anyone could shed some light I would be most grateful.

I just updated (through VS) Xamarin. Now the older solutions I had won't load. If I create a new solution, I've got the same Resource does not exist error. Xamarin appears to be broken. I've worked with it in the past and had no problems like these.

Comment: Please add the code, which producing the error

Comment: I have similar problem. Even a simple HelloWorld application with just one Textview is giving the similar problem of " 'Resource' does not exist in current context".

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it. My Xamarin version was not updated. I updated it by going to 
Programs & Features => Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, click on change/modify. Now in Visual Studio Popup under Cross Platform Mobile Developement update the C#/.NET (Xamarin v__). After updating this error gets resolved.

For me I didn't required to install Visual Studio 2017.

Also Thanks Martin for your suggestion, your answer can also workaround but it is not necessary to install 2017 just need to upgrade Xamarin version to work with VS 2015.

Comment: Good to know! It might mean the already fixed the problem :-) .

Answer (score 0):

This bug currently arises with Visual Studio 2015. See [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/315063#Comment_315063) and [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/112886/the-name-resource-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context) on the Xamarin Forums. Apparently the only workarounds now is to **install Visual Studio 2017** or **downgrade to older version of Xamarin**. There is also an opened [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=61135) for this, so it hopefully should get resolved soon.